# Issue deploying Python Flask Package, more specifically unable to open database file

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, operationalerror

The Error message that shows up is `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)`
And the Traceback stated the error as `fighters = Fighter.query.all()`
I have tried different methods of `

fighters.query.get(Fighter)

`
I just tried

> fighters = Fighter.query.order_by('id').all()

And i had gotten the same error which leads me to think its an issue initializing the database or possibly the database path.

I am unsure whether it is creating the database is the issue or querying the results.

My code in the run.py file is as follows-

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)

# DATABASE_URL is by default

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///tmp/test.db')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.email


class Fighter(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)


class Vote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('votes', lazy='dynamic'))
    fighter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fighter.id'))
    fighter = db.relationship('Fighter', backref=db.backref('votes', lazy='dynamic'))


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    fighters = Fighter.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', fighters=fighters)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my init_db.py file goes as follows-

```
from run import db, Fighter

# Create all the tables
db.create_all()

# create fighters
conor = Fighter(name='Conor McGregor')
floyd = Fighter(name='Floyd Mayweather')

# add fighters to session
db.session.add(conor)
db.session.add(floyd)

# commit the fighters to database
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Is your `init_db.py` file being run at all? The error indicates that no file `/tmp/test.db` exists, which may mean your database isn't created before you're trying to query from it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///tmp/test.db'
```

instead of this

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///tmp/test.db')
```

Comment: Thank you Ajay, when i ran it i still got the same error "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file", pointing towards the line "fighters = Fighter.query.all()". I think the issue is the defining of the database somehow

Comment: The issue is still persisting when making this change, when i took the tmp/ out i got error associated with the not being tables associated with Fighers